# Inline use of non-default explicit constructor for a member object

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In C++11 (or future), is there some simple variation of the following which is legal?

```
class A
   {
public:
   std::vector<char> b(123); // declare a vector with 123 elements
   };
```

The closest I can find is a bit clunky, and maybe inefficient...

```
class A
   {
public:
   std::vector<char> b = std::vector<char>(123);
   };
```

I'm trying to avoid using an initializer list.  I prefer to consolidate the declaration and initialization of `b` into a single line of code.  The vector will always be the same size.

I'm using `std::vector` in this example, but presumably the answer would be more generally applicable.

---

For good measure, here's the error message from `gcc` version 4.8:

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant
>       std::vector b(123);

and here's the message from `clang` version 3.7:

> error: expected parameter declarator
>         std::vector b(123);

Comment: Is `std::vector<char> b = decltype(b)(123);` less clunky?

Comment: @RSahu: I like that.  It's an improvement -- less redundancy.

Comment: "maybe" inefficient?  If your compiler does not elide?

Comment: You can expect elision from a modern compiler - see [`copy_elision` on *cpprefrence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for an overview.

Comment: @Yakk - Yes, that's what I meant.  It's hard to be confident about optional optimizations.

Comment: @TonyD, I get what you are saying. However, with C++11 the copy elision may not be required, because `X x = X(N);` invokes `X(X&&)` for the object `x`; hence the temporary object is *moved* to the new object  x (where `X` is `std::vector`). So there shouldn't be a question of efficiency or compiler optimization here. The optimization is implied by language feature of rvalue & `std::move`. Regarding clunkyness, one can always use `using` as mentioned by one of the answers.

Comment: @iammilind: with C++11's `vector` move constructor there's no prospect of the 123 *values* needing to be copied rather than moved, but an unoptimised move still implies prior lhs default construction, swapping of pointers, a `delete[]` in the temporary's destructor having to check for `nullptr`: you would be relying on the optimiser to eliminate that.  The compiler's explicitly granted the right to elide in this case (despite inhibiting side effects such as heap fragmentation), so the question of optimising the move processing becomes moot.

Comment: @nobar: *"It's hard to be confident about optional optimizations."* - C++'s Standard Library requires such optimisations to perform well (e.g. per equivalent C): compiler writers have had a couple decades to iron the issues with simple cases like this.  If you're concerned, do a couple checks on the compilers you plan to use, but you'll go to a lot of unnecessary trouble - and write less concise and maintainable code - if you approach each such potential issue pessimistically.

Comment: *"The vector will always be the same size."* - if you don't have other reasons for specifically wanting a `vector`, you could consider `std::array<char, 123> b;`.

Comment: @TonyD: `std::array` is probably the best solution for my current problem (but doesn't exactly answer the question).  I probably would have thought of that in the morning. :)

Comment: @nobar if you cannot trust basic elision, then why trust that `int x = 1+1;` doesn't send a web request to google to double check the math?  (That is optional -- ie, allowed -- under the standard).  An abysmal compiler that actively generates bad code, like failing to elide in easy cases, is a paranoia problem. I am aware of exactly zero C++11 compliers that fail to elide (barring insane compiler settings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highly unlikely. The original proposal to allow NSDMIs in the first place addresses this issue:

> [N2756](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm)
>
> ## An issue raised in Kona regarding scope of identifiers:
>
> During discussion in the Core Working Group at the September ’07
>   meeting in Kona, a question arose about the scope of identifiers in
>   the initializer. Do we want to allow class scope with the possibility
>   of forward lookup; or do we want to require that the initializers be
>   well-defined at the point that they’re parsed?
>
> ### What’s desired:
>
> The motivation for class-scope lookup is that we’d like to be able to
>   put anything in a non-static data member’s initializer that we could
>   put in a mem-initializer without significantly changing the semantics
>   (modulo direct initialization vs. copy initialization):
>
> ```
> int x();
>
> struct S {
>     int i;
>     S() : i(x()) {} // currently well-formed, uses S::x()
>     // ...
>     static int x();
> };
>
> struct T {
>     int i = x(); // should use T::x(), ::x() would be a surprise
>     // ...
>     static int x();
> };
> ```
>
> #### Problem 1:
>
> Unfortunately, this makes initializers of the “**(** *expression-list* **)**”
>   form ambiguous at the time that the declaration is being parsed:
>
> *...*
>
> #### The proposal:
>
> CWG had a 6-to-3 straw poll in Kona in favor of class-scope lookup;
>   and that is what this paper proposes, with initializers for non-static
>   data members limited to the “**=** *initializer-clause*” and “**{**
>   *initializer-list* *}*” forms. We believe:
>
> **Problem 1**: This problem does not occur as we don’t propose the **()**
>   notation. The **=** and **{}** initializer notations do not suffer from this
>   problem.

There is nothing inefficient about the clunky way of initialization unless your compiler doesn't employ copy elision (and all major ones do). The issue is that the language designers of C++ have backed themselves into a corner. Because initializer list constructors are *greedy*, brace initialization will construct a vector with the given *elements*, while the older syntax using parentheses calls the explicit constructor to set a size.

Except you can't use that constructor in a NSDMI. Unless you use an equals sign.

If for some reason that bothers you, there are some clunky workarounds:

```
std::vector<char> c = decltype(c)(123);
// ...
using VChar = std::vector<char>;
VChar v = VChar(123);
```

Or realize that new features do not preclude existing features:

```
std::vector<char> c;

A() : c(123)
{
}
```